# Catch the Plane problem from ACM ICPC 2018 world finals

Tags: algorithm, math

It's about a few days that I am thinking about the algorithm of [this problem](https://open.kattis.com/problems/catch). I've come up with different solutions but none of them got the right output. I was thinking about the directed acyclic graph but it seems that the passenger can do a round-trip, for example, from station 0 to 3, and then from 3 to 0, and then 0 to 1. I would appreciate if someone can describe the algorithm(not the code) of this problem. For making it easier to look up, I put the problem here, as well.

> Your plane to the ICPC Finals departs in a short time, and the only
> way to get to the airport is by bus. Unfortunately, some of the bus
> drivers are considering going on strike, so you do not know whether
> you can get to the airport on time. Your goal is to plan your journey
> in such a way as to maximize the probability of catching your plane.
> You have a detailed map of the city, which includes all the bus
> stations. You are at station 0 and the airport is at station 1. You
> also have a complete schedule of when each bus leaves its start
> station and arrives at its destination station. Additionally, for each
> bus you know the probability that it is actually going to run as
> scheduled, as opposed to its driver going on strike and taking the bus
> out of service. Assume all these events are independent. That is, the
> probability of a given bus running as planned does not change if you
> know whether any of the other buses run as planned. If you arrive
> before the departure time of a bus, you can transfer to that bus. But
> if you arrive exactly at the departure time, you will not have enough
> time to get on the bus. You cannot verify ahead of time whether a
> given bus will run as planned – you will find out only when you try to
> get on the bus. So if two or more buses leave a station at the same
> time, you can try to get on only one of them.
>
> ## **Input**
>
> The first line of input contains two integers m (1 ≤ m ≤ 10^6 ) and n (2 > ≤ n ≤ 10^6 ), denoting the number of buses and the number of stations in > the city. The next line contains one integer
> k (1 ≤ k ≤ 10^18 ), denoting the time by which you must arrive at the
> airport. Each of the next m lines describes one bus. Each line
> contains integers a and b (0 ≤ a, b < n, a != b), denoting the start
> and destination stations for the bus. Next are integers s and t (0 ≤ s
> < t ≤ k), giving the departure time from station a and the arrival
> time at station b. The last value on the line is p (0 ≤ p ≤ 1, with at
> most 10 digits after the decimal point), which denotes the probability
> that the bus will run as planned.
>
> ## **Output**
>
> Display the probability that you will catch your plane, assuming you
> follow an optimal course of action. Your answer must be correct to
> within an absolute error of 10^−6 .
>
> #### **Sample Input**
>
> ```
> 8 4
> 1000
> 0 1 0 900 0.2
> 0 2 100 500 1.0
> 2 1 500 700 1.0
> 2 1 501 701 0.1
> 0 3 200 400 0.5
> 3 1 500 800 0.1
> 3 0 550 650 0.9
> 0 1 700 900 0.1
> ```
>
> #### **Sample Output**
>
> ```
> 0.3124
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the arrival event associated with each scheduled trip.

If you participate in an arrival, i.e., if you actually successfully take the scheduled trip, then you end up at the station at the arrival time and you decide what to do from there.

For each arrival you can easily calculate the best probability of making your flight, if you already know the best probabilities for the arrivals you could possibly get to next.

Since the arrivals you could possibly get to next are all *later*, if you process all the possible arrivals in reverse chronological order, you can calculate the best probability for making your flight after each arrival, using only probabilities that you will already have calculated.

The process ends with the best probability for your initial arrival at station 0.

If you're clever in the implementation the whole thing takes O(N log N) time.